# How to filter dataframe DatetimeIndex with contains

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe indexed by datetime. I am trying to create filter of some sort that only provides frames that contain a specific time.

So for example, all frames that contain "09:30"

```
df.dtypes
open             float64
high             float64
low              float64
close            float64
volume             int64
returns          float64
returns_final      int64
dtype: object
```

I can do this based on the beginning of a frame, but I can't figure out if we can use wildcard type filters.

```
df.loc['2020'].head(5)

                    open        high         low        close         volume    returns returns_final
Datetime                            
2020-07-06 09:30:00 255.337982  261.950012  253.208786  261.421997  6592145 -6.084015   1
2020-07-06 11:00:00 261.526001  268.399994  261.239990  266.275452  4955678 -4.749451   1
2020-07-06 12:30:00 266.269043  266.989990  264.200012  265.191986  2002640 1.077057    -1
2020-07-06 14:00:00 265.185455  269.558014  261.597992  268.513763  3303263 -3.328308   1
2020-07-06 15:30:00 268.528015  275.558014  268.096008  274.200012  2583149 -5.671997   1
2020-07-07 09:30:00 281.002014  285.641998  267.341980  277.621979  10130111    3.380035    -1
2020-07-07 11:00:00 278.000000  284.600006  276.536011  278.123718  4221461 -0.123718   1
2020-07-07 12:30:00 278.000000  282.000000  277.399994  280.131012  2394459 -2.131012   1
```

I am trying to find something along these lines

```
df.loc['*09:30*']
```

Thinking I might have to re-index this or something

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: Think I figured it out.

df.filter(like='09:30', axis=0)

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df[df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S') == '09:30:00']
```

Output:

```
                           open        high         low       close    volume   returns  return_final
Datetime                                                                                             
2020-07-06 09:30:00  255.337982  261.950012  253.208786  261.421997   6592145 -6.084015             1
2020-07-07 09:30:00  281.002014  285.641998  267.341980  277.621979  10130111  3.380035            -1
```

For multiple times of day:

```
df[df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S').isin(['09:30:00','11:00:00'])]
```

You can use filter, like you're doing with regex:

```
df.filter(regex='09:30|11:00', axis=0)
```

Output:

```
                                      open        high         low              close    volume  returns  return_final
Datetime                                                                                                              
2020-07-06 09:30:00 255.337982  261.950012  253.208786  261.421997  6592145 -6.084015  1.000000      NaN           NaN
2020-07-06 11:00:00 261.526001  268.399994  261.239990  266.275452  4955678 -4.749451  1.000000      NaN           NaN
2020-07-07 09:30:00 281.002014  285.641998  267.341980  277.621979           10130111  3.380035     -1.0           NaN
2020-07-07 11:00:00 278.000000  284.600006  276.536011  278.123718  4221461 -0.123718  1.000000      NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Do you know how I can add multiple times to this? df[df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S') == '09:30:00'&'11:00:00']   ??

Comment: Use isin with a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it works.

```
df.filter(like='09:30', axis=0)

    open    high    low close   volume  returns returns_final
Datetime                            
2020-07-06 09:30:00 255.337982  261.950012  253.208786  261.421997  6592145 -6.084015   1
2020-07-07 09:30:00 281.002014  285.641998  267.341980  277.621979  10130111    3.380035    -1
2020-07-08 09:30:00 281.000000  283.399994  277.662018  278.865784  4698944 2.134216    -1
2020-07-09 09:30:00 279.398010  281.500000  271.919983  272.015991  4562064 7.382019    -1
2020-07-10 09:30:00 278.220367  283.799988  275.202026  283.506012  4274774 -5.285645   1
```